# Mercurial: List all transplanted change sets for a particular changeset hash

Tags: mercurial

In a repo with multiple branches suppose there is a commit which is in default branch and transplanted to some branches. Is there a way to list all the changesets which are created as a result of the transplant of that commit?

Comment: See if `hg log -r "destination(THAT_COMMIT)"` works for you.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - it must be answer, because we haven't better way (in common case)

Comment: OK, reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, obtained by executing `hg help revsets` we can see that:

```
"destination([set])"
  Changesets that were created by a graft, transplant or rebase operation,
  with the given revisions specified as the source.  Omitting the optional
  set is the same as passing all().
```

So, assuming you have a changeset known either by its local revision number or its hash, you can execute this command to see the transplant destinations:

```
hg log -r "destinations(CHANGESET)"
```

Where `CHANGESET` is the revision number or changeset hash.